# Numpy - How do the following loop for covariance

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop

I am asking a similar question to this [Numpy - Covariance between row of two matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69236194/numpy-covariance-between-row-of-two-matrix), but in this case I am not interested about the most efficient method, but just rewrite the for loop with some numpy functions. Is it possible convert the following code, without for loop, using numpy? Thanks in advance

Code:

```
m1 = np.array([[1,2,3],[2,2,2]])
m2 = np.array([[2.56, 2.89, 3.76],[1,2,3.95]])

output = []
for a,b in zip(m1,m2):
    cov = np.cov(a, b)
    output.append(cov[0][1])
print(output)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this out.

```
mycov = np.cov(m1, m2)

output = mycov.diagonal(offset=m1.shape[0])
```

Comment: Simple and fast. The best answer :D

Comment: I like this answer

Comment: @John_maddon This is overkill because it wastes about 7/8 of its time computing the irrelevant elements. Still well seen though.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I agree, I answered using this method since he said he doesn't care about efficieny.

Comment: For this method I do not care about efficiency, I need a numpy version to compute some derivatives, and they works just with numpy.. Thanks anyway! @MadPhysicist

Comment: @John_maddon. Why not a bit of both?

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid computing any extra elements by taking the relevant sum directly:

```
print(((m1 - m1.mean(1, keepdims=True)) * (m2 - m2.mean(1, keepdims=True))).sum(1) / (m1.shape[1] - 1))
```

It's just a product of the corresponding de-meaned vectors multiplied together, summed, and normalized by `n-1`.